# How Get back all "Customer" objects and only their "Order"s that are "Open" in Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I know how to get customers and all their orders:

```
//Get data context for the SQL Server connection
DataContext connection = new DataContext(getConnection());

//Customer table to query against
Table<Customer> customers = connection.GetTable<Customer>();

//This query gives all customers and ALL their orders
IQueryable<Customer> query = 
    from customer in customer
    where customer.id == custId select customer;
```

But how do I get the customer only with its orders that are `status = "Open"`?

Classes:

```
[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    ...elided...

    private EntitySet<Order> _orders;

    [Association(Storage = "_orders", OtherKey = "orderId")]
    public EntitySet<Order> orders
    {
        get
        {
            return this._orders;
        }

        set
        {
            this._orders.Assign(value);
        }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "Orders")]
public class Order
{
    ...elided...
    private string _status;

    [Column(Storage="_status")]
    public string _status
    {
        get { return this._status; }
        set { this._status = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly query customer after your first query since its an IQueryable so

```
var onlyOpen = customer.where(x=> x.orders._status = "Open");
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this with `DataLoadOptions`:

```
public virtual void addAssociationFilter<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> filter, DataContext dataContext)
{
    //We'll use this to restrict our main object's entity list property
    DataLoadOptions restrictList = new DataLoadOptions();

    //We only want ops that are current or finished
    restrictList.AssociateWith<T>(filter);

    //Set on our context
    dataContext.LoadOptions = restrictList;
}

//Call like:
addAssociationFilterJCustomer>(
    cust => cust.orders.Where(o => o.status == "Open"),
    dataContext
);
```